# How would I repeat a mouse's USB signal, but also being able to modify the signal?

Tags: mouse

For an upcoming project, I need to make a mouse repeater for a Raspberry Pi, but I also need to be able to modify the signal. I need to be able to send certain button clicks from a script. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does repeater mean in this context? Do you want to use the modified input on the PI, or send it to another USB host?

Comment: You should search for and read about USB, it is an entire protocol, MUCH more than a few wires.

Comment: Ditto.  However, you can do this more easily by bypassing USB via `/dev/uinput`: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/input/uinput.html  You can monitor an actual mouse via `evdev`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev

Comment: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/
sending HID outputs are only possible on some models i believe( pi zero being one of them). I was not able to find directions but i hope what little i can offer helps :).